# rails find_by_object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know the rails method find_by_name but what if instead of a name I have an object? Assuming I have `@car` and `@brand` objects. How can I search for all `cars` that have a specific `brand` object.

Something like `@cars = Car.find_by_brand(@brand)`

I have tried `@cars = @brand.cars` but that only seems to pull one parent model.

**Edit - More info on code**

Car controller:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
```

Brands model:

```
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
```

Brands Controller

```
def create
@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
@brand = Brand.create
@brand.assign_attributes({ :name => params[:brand][:brands][:name] })
@brand.cars << @car
if @brand.save
  redirect_to @car
else
  flash[:notice] = "Error!"
  redirect_to @car
end
end

def findcars
    @brand = Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand_name])
    @cars = @brand.cars
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to brand.name, findcars_car_brand_path(@car, brand_name: brand.name), method: "get" %>
```

**Routes**

```
resources :cars do    
    resources :brands do
        member { get :findcars }
    end
end
```

**Tables** - There is no model for the join table

`brands (name:string)`

`cars (name:string)`

`brands_cars (brand_id:integer, car_id:integer)`

Comment: Can you show the relevant chunk of the model definitions?  '@cars = @brand.cars' ought to work based on what I am guessing you're doing, but guessing is only fun for a few minutes.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at findcars first. **.joins(:brands)** is key as it allows you to narrow the query via brand conditions (**'brands.attribute' => brand_value**), while building Car objects.

The SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" INNER JOIN "cars_brands" ON "cars_brands"."car_id" = "cars"."id" INNER JOIN "brands" ON "brands"."id" = "cars_brands"."brand_id" WHERE "brands"."id" = 1
```

and the implementation like this:

```
# If all you care about is the @cars - as the method name indicates
def findcars
    @cars = Car.joins(:brands).where('brands.name' => params[:brand_name])
end
# If you need both variables
def findcars
    @brand = Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand_name])
    @cars = Car.joins(:brands).where('brands.id' => @brand)
end
```

Without the joins, your sql looks like this:

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "brands"."id" = 1
```

This will break as 'brands' means nothing in this context.  You need to give rails a little more detail so it can build the query properly.

Now the **create** method:

```
# @brand = Brand.create
# @brand.assign_attributes({ :name => params[:brand][:brands][:name] })
# params[:brand][:brands][:name] indicates something fishy with your form
# since this form is in the context of Brand, params[:name] should suffice 
@brand = Brand.create(:name => params[:brand][:brands][:name])
```

Does **redirect_to @car** mean that the form is a Car-centric form?  Using *form_for* in the correct context will simplify the object creation.

For 2 great overviews, check out:

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: your findcars code worked! three rails books and I have yet to come across this technique. Thank you so much! The page itself is to hold the attributes of a car with the create brand of the car form embedded within the page.